# emacs ERC commands conditional only if file exists

Tags: emacs, conditional-statements

I have the following in my emacs init file:

```
(if (file-readable-p "~/.ercpass") (load "~/.ercpass"))

(setq erc-nickserv-passwords
                `((freenode     (("jacob" . ,freenode-nickone-pass)))))
```

Only if `~/.ercpass` (its contents being `(setq freenode-nickone-pass "mypassword")`) is readable do I want the file to be loaded and the ERC password to used. If the file exists, everything works. But if it doesn't exist, the second line throws an error:

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: freenode-nickone-pass
```

How can I make the second line also conditional on whether `~/.ercpass` is readable?

Comment: How about just one if/then statement for everything using `progn`.  E.g., `(if green-eggs-and-ham (progn .....))` or `(when green-eggs-and-ham .....)`

Comment: Thanks for not supplying the full answer but rather giving me a hint. Made me use my brain ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
(if (file-readable-p "~/.ercpass")
    (progn
      (load "~/.ercpass")
      (setq erc-nickserv-passwords
            `((freenode     (("jacob" . ,freenode-nickone-pass)))))))
```